# Singapore Employment Pass - age limitation

Tags: working-visas, employment, singapore

I am a US citizen. My employer is shutting its US legal entity, which hired me, effective 31 December 2017, and I am seeking transfer to its Singapore entity. I could be eligible for an employment pass as my base salary is over $11,000 per month. However, I am 58 years old.

**Are there any age limitations for applying for employment pass for employees being transferred to Singapore?**

Comment: are there any age limitations to apply for Singapore Employment Pass

Answer (score 4):

There is no age limit beyond the legal retirement age (62). As long as your company is willing to, and able to, sponsor an EP, you should be fine. Note that the salary is only one of the criteria (education is another). You can do the self-assessment [here](https://services.mom.gov.sg/sat/satservlet). Also, the decision is done on a case-by-case basis, with very little transparency.